# Is there an azure REST API request to retrieve the latest successful build/run of a pipeline?

Tags: azure, api, devops

I am currently using a build pipeline to build a .net project, I need to access the most recent successful build.

I am currently using the request:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/Sportcast/Cluster%20Deployments/_apis/build/latest/Build-cb?branchName=$branch&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

This will return the latest build, be it success or fail.

How can i retrieve the latest successful build?

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#build implies there is a data structure returned, including a property of `BuildResult`. Do you get anything like that when you call that API?

Comment: Yes, The property of "BuildResult" Will indicate either success or fail. However this request only returns the most recent build. If the most recent build was a fail, I still don't have a way to access the most recent successful build.

Comment: Looks like there is no direct API for that I guess you need to get the history and look through the response for the most recent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/history/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#buildretentionsample

Answer (score 2):

you can get the latest succeeded build:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={builddefinitionid}&resultFilter=succeeded&statusFilter=completed&maxBuildsPerDefinition=1&queryOrder=finishTimeDescending
```

Comment: I just tried this and everything except the maxBuildsPerDefinition seems to work. Anyone know if this is a bug, or if there is a workaround? The parameter is correct according tot he api documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0