# How to get the result of the latest/last pipeline build in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps, I am trying to get the result of the latest/last pipeline on a branch for a pipeline. This is to check if the previous build on the branch is failed due to some errors and after fixing the errors, the pipeline should trigger corresponding to the commit to the branch. If the branch has a successful build, the pipeline should skip the build.

I am trying to get result from the using below command to get the result using Azure DevOps API call which works fine in the browser but gives null when run through the pipeline.

```
previousRunId=$(curl -u ":$(System.AccessToken)" -X GET "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(System.DefinitionId)&branchName=$(Build.SourceBranch)&$top=1" | jq '.value[0].result')
echo "Previous run status: ${previousRunId}"
```

[image]

How to get the actual result as below?

[image]

Comment: Similar thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647453/is-there-an-azure-rest-api-request-to-retrieve-the-latest-successful-build-run-o

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception in your script. You may find the following message If you run your command without `jq`:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The buildIds filter may
> not be used with other filter
> parameters.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.InvalidBuildQueryException,
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"InvalidBuildQueryException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

You have to escape `$top`

```
$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(System.DefinitionId)&branchName=$(Build.SourceBranch)&\$top=1
```

Comment: Correct, even after running the command without jq I am getting the above error.
Used below commad 

curl -u ":$(System.AccessToken)" -X GET "$(System.CollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProjectId)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(System.DefinitionId)&branchName=$(Build.SourceBranch)&$top=1"

Comment: @LikithJ use `\$top` instead of `$top`

Comment: Thank You this worked, and I am able to get the result value. 
But when this is run on a new branch the first build gives result as null since it is the first build on the branch and if ran second time on the same branch it is taking the result value of the second build instead of the first build and if ran third time then it gives the result of second build. 

Expected Result
1st build - null
2nd build - result of 1st build
3rd build - result of 2nd build

Actual Result
1st build - null
2nd build - result of 2nd build - now working as expected here
3rd build - result of 2nd build

Comment: @LikithJ, 2nd build `cannot` get result of 2nd build as it's still running.  You have `branchName` in the rest api url, please make sure you didn't change branch between different build runs. Or you can remove this parameter in the url to get the build result no matter which branch it is.

Comment: @LikithJ, as wadezhou-MSFT says, you additionally receive the current build. To exclude it, you may try to add statusFilter=completed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2#buildstatus

Comment: @LikithJ, the sample shared in the reply works fine on my side, may i know if you still have any queries? Please make sure you didn't change the branch between different runs.